# getting permission denied after using chmod +x on Linux while executing Java program

Tags: java, linux, permissions, chmod

Here is my executable file:

```
  #!/bin/bash
  JAVA_HOME=/cad2/ece419s/java/jdk1.6.0/
  # arguments to GameServer
  # $1 = port # where GameServer is listening

  ${JAVA_HOME}bin/java GameServer $1
```

I run the `chmod` command as:

```
  chmod +x server.sh
```

And then:

```
  ./ server.sh 8000
```

8000 is the port from local computer which my server is listening to.

After `bash -x server.sh 8000`, I got [image: this]

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Command not found error after ./server.sh 8000

Comment: Best I can suggest from here is to ensure (1) the chmod actually worked: try `ls -l server.sh`  (2) that you are in the same directory as server.sh, (3) that `/bin/bash` actually exists, (4) that you can run the script without the shebang via `bash -x server.sh 8000`.

Comment: i got another error after using                                     bash -x server.sh 8000. + JAVA_HOME=$'/cad2/ece419s/java/jdk1.6.0/\r'
+ $'/cad2/ece419s/java/jdk1.6.0/\rbin/java' GameServer $'8000\r'
bin/java: No such file or directoryva/jdk1.6.0/

Comment: Sorry, the quotes, the `\r` characters and the phrase "No such file or directoryva/jdk1.6.0" look all wrong to me.

Comment: I edit the question by adding the picture of what i exactly got.

Comment: Very strange.  The carriage return charactrers might have something to do with it.  Not sure how they got into your code.

Comment: Is there any possibility that the problem is because of something inside GameServer?

Comment: Maybe you can try running each command one by one.  If they all work then maybe get help from someone in person putting it all in a script.  I am out of ideas.

Comment: thank you very much for your time and trying to help, really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you write this `server.sh` script on other platform (maybe Windows) and copy it to a Linux system, and these two systems use different character for end-of-line, so try to convert it to Linux format first by `dos2unix server.sh`.

---

If your system does not have `dos2unix`, you can install it by

1. on Fedora `yum install dos2unix`
2. on Debian `apt-get install dos2unix`

Both need root privilege.

If you cannot or does not want to install `dos2unix`, another option is using `vim` (it should be avariable in a normal Linux machine):

1. `vim server.sh`
2. `:set ff=unix`
3. `:w`

Comment: all files i have got are written on Linux. But for any case i tried dos2unix server.sh, i got dos2unix: Command not found

Comment: @user1722022 Then you need to install `dos2unix` first, please see my updated answer.

Comment: i do not have root privilege because i use university lab station machines, i am not allowed to do those

Comment: @user1722022 If you have `vim` installed, you can use it to do the conversion. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a space between `./` and `server.sh` so you are trying to execute `./`.

Comment: oh did not know that, i just tried without space and i got command not found for some reason

Comment: Is server.sh in the current directory?

Comment: Does the script run at all or do you get "command not found" when trying to run server.sh?  If server.sh can't be found in the current directory, that's weird.  Maybe the script is running but there is an error inside of it?  In that case you can read up on, and try, `bash -x`.

Comment: it does not run i get command not found error when trying to run server.sh. Do you mean writing command as bash -x ./server.sh 8000?

Comment: Yes.  Maybe the `chmod` didn't take.  Try `ls -l`.

Comment: This is what i got after ls -l server.sh: -rwxr-xr-x 1 huseynl1 cpe1T5 161 Feb 26 01:34 server.sh

Answer (score 0):

You can run command "ls -l" by going in previous directory and check whether the permissions are applied to the file or not.

If not then check for the user whether he has change permissions or not. Else you can use "root" user who mostly has all the permissions.

[image: as mentioned in the image]

Comment: I think i am not permitted to "root" user since i am using university machines